# Python Selenium is too slow

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have the the following code.
Unfortunately the code is really slow on my M1 Mac. My Internet connection is really fast but the Chrome Window is loading so slow. The animation when my programm maximizes the window looks also like it has just 10 fps.
I have already tried to get rid of the `driver.maximize_window()` command, but it
doesn´t change anything. Besides that why do I have to initialize a ChromeDriver? It also works if I remove the `service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())` argument.
Do you have any ideas?
I really appreciate any kind of help.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com/xhtml")
driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `ChromeDriverManager().install()` will try to use the downloaded version from DriverCacheManager which I'm not sure how operates. If Cache manager is not getting the cached result every time - this means your driver will be downloaded and installed every time you run the script.
As far as I remember you can install the Chrome driver on your own and then just provide a path to it, maybe this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have now installed the ChromeDriver and it did´t change anything! :(